# SQLAlchemy Listener for when column value is accessed

Tags: sqlalchemy

I see a listener can be setup for ‘set’ on a table column. Is there a way to setup a listener for when a certain column is queried and the value accessed in the ORM table object class?

Tried setting up a listener on the whole table and evaluating the query. The query seems to always pull every column.

Comment: Can you provide some context on what you are trying to achieve?